# Matlab Query builder: Define ODBC Data Source

Tags: mysql, database, matlab, database-connection

I am using matlab database toolbox to extract data from Server. I am not familiar with SQL database apart from how to establish a connection from matlab using sql query. How can I check matlab is using which drivers to access the database as I mistakenly changed the drivers via 'Define ODBC data source' in query builder to MYSQL ODBC 5.1 Driver, due to that

```
con_semilib = database('checkdatabase','root','*******')
e=exec(con_semilib,['SELECT *FROM movies WHERE movie_id=1 ']);
e=fetch(e);
e.Data %e.Data is giving me ans=0
```

Any suggestions, I am not so familiar with database toolbox. Thanks
Adding to it, it was working fine before I messed with this define ODBC datasource
[image]

Comment: Any suggestions??? How can I ensure to revert back to previous condition